# Exc after update dependencies pom.xm Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationAotProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationAotProcessor
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.system.DevToolsEnablementDeducer.<clinit>(DevToolsEnablementDeducer.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:534)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236)
    at com.inventoryweb.InventoryWebApplication.main(InventoryWebApplication.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 16 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Very thankful for your time.

**This is my pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- Run specific spring boot profile through command line -->
    <!-- ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles={profile_name} -->

    <!-- Run integration tests -->
    <!-- ./mvnw verify -P integration-test -->

    <!-- Run unit tests -->
    <!-- ./mvnw clean install -DskipITs -->

    <!-- Build specific war profiles without running IT -->
    <!-- ./mvnw clean install -P<profile> package -DskipTests -->

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.inventoryweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>inventoryweb</artifactId>
    <version>SNAPSHOT.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <!-- Test -->
        <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
        <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
        <project.finalName>${project.artifactId}-${env.name}-${project.version}</project.finalName>
        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <tomcat.version>9.0.40</tomcat.version>
        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <springframework.version>5.3.9</springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.finalName}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Used for unit tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Integration tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- States that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe
                        Maven plugin are executed. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests
                                property is true -->
                            <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Provides commit hash -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.9.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
                    </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <includeOnlyProperties>
                        <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.abbrev$</includeOnlyProperty>
                        <includeOnlyProperty>^git.branch$</includeOnlyProperty>
                    </includeOnlyProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Data base migration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Allow custom validation messages for annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        &lt;!&ndash; To compile JSP files &ndash;&gt;-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provides configuration tools for lifecycle application events -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Useful dependency to restart and quick pick up configuration changes
            (Server (Domain) and Client side - JSP) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provides proper dependencies for DB interaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC connection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <!--Auto generate property setters and getters together with constructors-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Templates este-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime data base access for test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Db migrations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Conditional Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ASI-Graylog Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.siegmar</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Encrypt properties sensitive information -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Allows testing security configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Allows toString by reflection which is useful on logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Password validation rules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Messages joiner (Consider implementing project utility instead of adding another library) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Allow to work whit json-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ittest</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>ittest</build.profile.id>
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
                <env.name>dev</env.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>qa</spring.profiles.active>
                <env.name>qa</env.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
                <env.name>prod</env.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: You are mixing version of SPring boot 2.3.12, 2.5, 3.0.0 and wonder why things aren't working. Start by removing all the `version` tags from the `org.springframework.boot` dependencies, remove the version for the `spring-security-test` dependency and use `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6` instead of 5. Also remove the `springframework.version` property. Use a `java.version` in your `properties` block to set the java version and remove the compiler plugin.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I already fixed my pom. I had to add  <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>runtime</scope> in devtools